# Atom/Typescript UI indicators confusing

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

Using the Atom Typescript plugin, which is pretty awesome!

I am confused by the orange small dot to the left of line 74, and orange bigger dot to the right of line 75.

Also what is the "references (no search)" in the ts status bar trying to tell me? In fact can I customize that status bar at all to not be so cluttered and more useful?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> orange small dot to the left of line 74,

Atom: Means that this line is changed. Basically `Git diff`

> orange bigger dot to the right of line 75.

Linter: is reporting that there is an error in this line

> what is the "references (no search)"

Find references : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#find-references

Comment: In actuality no. But linter thinks there is. Notice "File 1" in the status bar linter panel.

Comment: ah that's the linter panel!? I guess I don't need linter given that typescript/atom shows me errors right away...

Comment: FWIW the latest release of linter has been very kind. The plan is to work within the atom ecosystem and use the logic from the linter as much as possible (remove our custom *errors in files* tab). It already is the only thing managing the *underlines* and highlights within the file